# Node.js - Gunzip an already read file async issues

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript, promise, gunzip

Relatively new to node.js and the async way of doing things, so far I've been able to use promises to read a file using fs readFile, but I haven't had any luck getting zlib Gunzip to work. Writing in Coffeescript:

```
   promisifyRun(fs, 'readFile', filepath, 'utf-8')
    .then (file) ->
      promisifyRun(zlib, 'Gunzip', file)
        .then (data) ->
          console.log "HELLO"
          return data
    .catch respondError res
```

**promisfyRun** is for promising a single function (I didn't write it, but it does work). I've managed to successfully use it for the fs.readFile component, like so:

```
   promisifyRun(fs, 'readFile', filepath, 'utf-8')
    .then (data) ->
      return data
    .catch respondError res
```

This works just fine, it waits for the file to be opened and then continues. 'data' contains the body of the file. I figure it should be a pretty logical extension to incorporate the gunzip component, but so far that has been a challenge.

I've looked at a few npm gunzip modules. The one that seems most interesting is the [gunzip-maybe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gunzip-maybe) or [zlib.Gunzip](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/zlib.html#zlib_class_zlib_gunzip) (which I am attempting here).

The error message for this particular case has been:

> "Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

which I think is related to the process already having been completed cause of its asynchronicity

**Update** -- Full stacktrace:

> Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (/Users/jcook/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:725:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (/Users/jcook/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
>       at ServerResponse.json (/Users/jcook/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:256:15)
>       at ServerResponse.send (/Users/jcook/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
>       at /Users/jcook/project/.tmp/lib/util.js:40:22
>       at tryCatcher (/Users/jcook/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/jcook/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/jcook/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/jcook/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/jcook/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:689:18)
>       at Async._drainQueue (/Users/jcook/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
>       at Async._drainQueues (/Users/jcook/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/jcook/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)

Comment: What is the full stacktrace?

Comment: Please post the code that is sending the headers. Your `util.tryCatcher` (or the code that uses it) might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see the `Can't set headers after they're sent`, it's almost always because your request handler is still executing after the endpoint has responded, which IME is 99% related to code not waiting for callbacks to complete.

To start, you're negating a lot of the benefits of using promises by not chaining your promises.

```
promisifyRun(fs, 'readFile', filepath, 'utf-8')
.then (file) ->
  // Just return another promise here.
  return promisifyRun(zlib, 'Gunzip', file)
.then (data) ->
   console.log "HELLO"
   return data
.catch respondError res
```

Second, you are running `return data` from inside a callback. My guess is that you are trying to use a return value on the other side like so:

```
run = ()->
  promisifyRun(fs, 'readFile', filepath, 'utf-8')
  .then (file) ->
    // Just return another promise here.
    return promisifyRun(zlib, 'Gunzip', file)
  .then (data) ->
     console.log "HELLO"
     return data
  .catch respondError res

myData = run()
```

This doesn't work because what's being returned from the promise is asynchronous. You need to handle the response async:

```
run = ()->
  promisifyRun(fs, 'readFile', filepath, 'utf-8')
  .then (file) ->
    // Just return another promise here.
    return promisifyRun(zlib, 'Gunzip', file)
  // We remove the rest of the function, 
  // so it just returns the promise above.

run().then (data)->
  console.log data
```

Once CS 2.0 lands, you'll be able to use ES6 async/await:

```
data = await run()
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks for such a thorough reply, I've just been learning about promises and I think it's taken me a bit to wrap my head around their intended utility.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward and efficient way to do this is to stream it, using the fs and zlib modules that come with node:

```
fs.createReadStream('./file.gz')
  .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
  .pipe(res);
```

If in your case you have only the buffer of the file contents, then `zlib.gunzip` suffices:

```
zlib.gunzip(buffer, (err, gunzippedBuffer) => {
  // ...
});
```

See https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_gunzip_buf_options_callback

Comment: I've tried the first option, but I get a message that says 'TypeError: fs.createReadStream(...).pipe is not a function'